# Is there any straight way to establish P2P UDP connection behind NAT in delphi?

Tags: delphi, udp, indy, p2p, nat

I've been trying to establish a P2P connections for a couple of weeks. After writing some code and using Indy's components, I've realized that it can not access the peer that is behind the NAT. Furthermore, I've heard about STUN services that provide a client's remote and local IPs and ports. I should say I've already had the other UDP client (server) remote and local IPs, so how can I implement my code and program to work properly? Is there any extra component in Indy's library that I should use?

Comment: There is nothing simple about implementing P2P protocols. There are many [NAT traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) techniques (hole punching, STUN/TURN, etc) you can try employing, but Indy has no specific components for most of them. It gives you access to the underlying UDP sockets, but you will have to implement the actual P2P protocols on top of them in your own code logic. It *CAN* be done, with enough effort (Skype proved that, which was originally written in Delphi with Indy, before Microsoft bought it), but it is not necessarily "straight forward".

Comment: Thank you Remy Lebeau for your straightforward answer, so I have to manipulate Indy's source code. Did I get it correctly? 
Would you help me with the best point that I should start from?

Comment: "*I have to manipulate Indy's source code. Did I get it correctly?*" - no, that is not what I said.

Comment: Sorry, It seems I've made a big copyright mistake. Word choosing is one of the big problems that I have as an English beginner. I meant writing some helpers for it by "manipulating", however, I hope I didn't upset you and Indy's developers.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Ares Galaxy P2P Project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/aresgalaxy/) I know about some years ago.

There was a recent fork by Christian at https://github.com/CWBudde/AresGalaxy which tries to port it to more modern Delphi versions.

It is a work in progress, but perhaps you may get some very good ideas in this source code, and ask Christian for help/ideas, especially about NAT transversal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. During my searching progress, I found UPnP intresting, but I've not found a straightforward implementation  to use it. I've seen some of codes using COM and oleObjects, but It seems it doesn't work at least for me :|